# How to get all mappings between two lists?

Tags: python, list, combinatorics, python-itertools

We have two lists, A and B:

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = [1, 2]
```

Is there a pythonic way to build the set of all maps between A and B containing 2^n (here 2^3=8)? That is:

```
[(a,1), (b,1), (c,1)]
[(a,1), (b,1), (c,2)]
[(a,1), (b,2), (c,1)]
[(a,1), (b,2), (c,2)]
[(a,2), (b,1), (c,1)]
[(a,2), (b,1), (c,2)]
[(a,2), (b,2), (c,1)]
[(a,2), (b,2), (c,2)]
```

Using `itertools.product`, it's possible to get all the tuples:

```
import itertools as it
P = it.product(A, B)
[p for p in P]
```

Which gives:

```
Out[3]: [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
from itertools import product
print [zip(A, item) for item in product(B, repeat=len(A))]
```

**Output**

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)],
 [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)],
 [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)],
 [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)],
 [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)],
 [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)],
 [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)],
 [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]]
```

`product(B, repeat=len(A))` produces

```
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 2)]
```

Then we pick each element from the product and zip it with `A`, to get your desired output.

Answer (score 11):

```
import itertools as it

A = ['a','b','c']
B = [1, 2]

for i in it.product(*([B]*len(A))):
    print(list(zip(A, i)))
```

outputs:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Not sure if it's very pythonic, it is if you look at `it.product(*([B]*len(A)))`, because it uses multiple python-specific language features. But it's actually too cryptic to be pythonic... B is repeated n-times based on length of A and unpacked to the product-function.