# How to get all possible orders of a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have 5 vertical strings which were generated in order of probability by my classifier.  If the classifiers confidence was very high I want to keep that classification but for the low ones I would like to vary between all possible orders of combinations creating a list of all possible vertical strings.

so my data looks like this:

```
aa aa aa aa aa
ab ac aa ad ae
aa ab af ae ag
```

and I would like to get all of the possible ordered combinations

```
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ...
ab ac aa ad ae ae ab ac aa ad ...
aa ab af ae ag aa ab af ae ag...
```

I tried itertools but I can't seem to find the right tool to do this. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import sys
import os
import itertools
from itertools import permutations

in_file = sys.argv[1]

f1 = open(in_file, 'r')

new_lines = []

for line in f1.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    do stuff to replace my higher confidence matches...
        new_lines.append(line)

for x in new_lines:
    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in permutations(x.split(), 10):
        print '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(a.rstrip('\n'), b.rstrip('\n'), c.rstrip('\n'), d.rstrip('\n'), e.rstrip('\n'), f.rstrip('\n'), g.rstrip('\n'), h.rstrip('\n'), i.rstrip('\n'), j.rstrip('\n'))
```

I tested this with 10 to make make sure it didn't explode but this does not seem to work the way I thought it would. If I put 5 it just gives me the same list I had before. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: So to confirm you want every possible unique sequence of n (10) objects from a set of x (5) inputs?

Comment: You can use `itertools.product` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058028/how-to-get-all-mappings-between-two-lists?rq=1)

Comment: @leumas95. I just put 10 to stop it. I really want all of the possible orders of each 5 element list.

Comment: @Gleland, I don't think so because in each line I just have 5 elements and not two lists... but it is kind of on its way.

Comment: @badner I see what you are doing, the limit is for the length of each permutation not the number of individual permutations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Python itertools.permutations method takes in an iterable and an integer limit (r).

The integer is used to limit the length of each permutation, for example, if you had a list of permutations([1, 2, 3], 2) would give you [(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 1),(2, 3),(3, 1),(3, 2)].

The limit must not be larger than the length of the input list or it will return an empty iterable.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations specifically "The number of items returned is n! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or zero when r > n."